# Case statement returning '0'

Tags: sql

I need this case statement to return an empty string if the value is null or `-1` however it's actually returning `0`. EmployeeCount is an `int` and I'm assuming it needs to be cast to varchar but nothing I've tried seems to be working.

```
CASE 
  WHEN EmployeeCount = -1 THEN ''
  WHEN EmployeeCount IS NULL THEN ''
  ELSE EmployeeCount
END
```

this not working either:

```
CASE 
  WHEN EmployeeCount = -1 THEN ''
  WHEN EmployeeCount IS NULL THEN ''
  ELSE CAST(EmployeeCount as varchar(10))
END
```

Comment: a column can't be both numeric and string data.  '' is string data 0 isn't.  Put another way a column can only be of one type.  since all numeric can be string but not all string can be numeric the system is implictly casting your datatype to character data.

Comment: do WHEN EmployeeCount IS NULL the first one

Comment: What @xQbert means is that you can't have the result of your case expression be two different datatypes. So you'll have to `cast(EmployeeCount as varchar(8))` for the `ELSE`

Comment: Try: `WHEN EmployeeCount = -1 THEN coalesce(cast(EmployeeCount as varchar(255)), '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a single type.  If you have some `then` clauses evaluate to strings and others evaluate to numbers, database will decide that the result is a number, not a string.  That is why you are seeing `0`.  That is what `''` looks like when converted to a number.

The solution is simple:  `cast()` the result to a string:

```
(CASE WHEN EmployeeCount = -1 OR EmployeeCount IS NULL THEN ''
      ELSE CAST(EmployeeCount as VARCHAR(32))
 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN EmployeeCount = -1 THEN ''
  WHEN EmployeeCount IS NULL THEN ''
  ELSE CAST(EmployeeCount as varchar(10))
END
AS COL1
FROM 
(SELECT -1 as EmployeeCount) t
```

... and it does return empty string, not 0, so there's nothing wrong with the SQL, something outside of SQL is converting it to 0.